# Estimators for Bernoulli trials

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution

I have failure data for an experience over  $T$  years: at the beginning of each year I have $n_t$ subjects and $d_t$ of these subjects experience a "failure" at the end of the year.

Now if I assume that the trials are iid Binomial and the probability of failure $p$ is homogenous (i.e. constant over time), the ML estimator is given by

$$\hat{p}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^T d_t}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^T n_t}$$

However, there is an alternate estimator:

$$\bar{p}=\frac{1}{T}\sum\limits_{i=1}^T \frac{d_t}{n_t}.$$

What would be the assumptions and the model so that the estimate is $\bar{p}$?

===========================

**EDIT:**

The question is not about the relative merits of the two estimators. For example, it is not necessary to assume homogeneity for the second estimator. I am wondering about the assumptions that would "naturally" lead to the second estimator.

===========================

**EDIT2:**

I am in a situation where $\bar{p}$ is imposed as an estimator. I need to come up with confidence intervals or credible intervals for the estimate. My idea was to determine the assumptions (possibly a hierarchical model) and do a MCMC using `JAGS`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model for estimator $\hat{p}$ is actually of a single system that was operated $n_i$ times in year $i$, $1 \leq i \leq T$, and failed $d_i$ times that year. Presumably the system was successfully repaired and restored to perfect working
condition before the next time it was operated.

Your model for estimator $\bar{p}$ is that of $n_i$ independent 
copies of Model $i$ of
the system being put in operation in year $i$ and $d_i$ of those copies
failing independently.  You wish to estimate the average failure rate 
per year over $T$ years.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both can be considered as estimators of $p$ for the same model under different 'estimating equations'. It $appears$ to me that both estimators have the same mean (see the discussion below). Therefore, I don't think biasedness is a useful criteria to pick one. Let me define $N:=\sum_{t=1}^T n_t$, then

$$\hat p = \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{d_t}{N} =\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{n_t}{N}\frac{d_t}{n_t} .$$

Therefore, if $n_t$ does not change much over time, $\frac{n_t}{N} \approx \frac{1}{T}$, the estimators will be very similar. But if this values are different, they will differ of course. Check the following R code for an illustration.

```
ss = c(10,50)
e1 = function(x) return(sum(x)/sum(ss))
e2 = function(x) return(mean(x/ss))
e1v = e2v = rep(0,100)
for(j in 1:100){
    x = rbinom(length(ss), size = ss, 0.5)
    e1v[j] = e1(x)
    e2v[j] = e2(x)
}
plot(e1v-e2v,type='l',col='red')
plot(e1v,type='l',col='red',ylim=c(0.2,0.8))
points(e2v,type='l',col='blue')
```

Second code

```
ss = seq(10,20,1)
e1 = function(x) return(sum(x)/sum(ss))
e2 = function(x) return(mean(x/ss))
e1v = e2v = rep(0,10000)
for(j in 1:10000){
x = rbinom(length(ss), size = ss, 0.5)
e1v[j] = e1(x)
e2v[j] = e2(x)
}

c(quantile(e1v,0.025),quantile(e1v,0.975))
 hist(e1v)

 c(quantile(e2v,0.025),quantile(e2v,0.975))
 hist(e2v)
```

Comment: @Dilip He is assuming that $p$, the failure rate, is homogeneous. Then, wishing to estimate the average failure rate is equivalent to estimate $p$. Your second statement is a tautology.

Comment: I like the approach--arguing from fundamental ideas--but it would be nice to see the calculations supporting the assumptions in the first paragraph.  It appears to *me* that the estimators have different variances except when all the $n_i$ are equal and otherwise the first estimator has smaller variance: this comes down to the famous (and elementary) inequality between the harmonic and arithmetic means.

Comment: But if the numbers $n_i$ differ significantly e.g. the number of subjects grow year by year, then $\hat{p}$ is dominated by the failures experienced in the most prolific years while $\bar{p}$ is less so. My gut feeling is that $\bar{p}$ is a better statistic for estimating $p$ than $\hat{p}$ is.

Comment: @whuber $d_t\sim Bin(n_t,p)$, then $E[d_t]=n_tp$. Taking linearity into account it follows that $E[\hat p] = E[\bar p] = p$ from which unbiasedness follows. You are completely right about the variances. I will modify my answer and I would like to see your calculation about the variances (given that you noticed this,  I don't want to steal the credit and maybe this will tell us which estimator is better).

Comment: @Dilip If $n_i$ differ but you assume homogeneity of the parameter $p$, then the likelihood function is the product of the likelihoods corresponding to each experiment from which you obtain the same estimator $\hat p$. I have the same feeling about which estimator is better.

Comment: There's no credit to be "stolen": my role is to help you improve your answer.  When that happens, I'm happy :-).  As I wrote, I like your approach and would like to see you support it with calculations like the one in your comment.  All you need do is exploit the fact that $\text{Var}(d_t)=n_tp(1-p)$.  Once you have compared the estimation variances quantitatively, I am curious whether that would change your conclusions.

Comment: @whuber $\text{Var}[\hat p] = \frac{p(1-p)}{\sum_{t=1}^Tn_t}$ and $\text{Var}[\bar p] =  \frac{p(1-p)}{T^2}\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{n_t}$. Therefore, if we compare these two estimators in terms of their variances, we can see that $\frac{\text{Var}[\hat p]}{\text{Var}[\bar p]}$ depends on the values of $n_t$ and $T$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the variances depend on the $n_t$, but we can still say something about them!  The ratio $\text{Var}[\hat{p}]/\text{Var}[\bar p]$, which reduces to the ratio of the harmonic mean of the $n_t$ to their arithmetic mean, never exceeds $1$ and equals $1$ if and only if all the $n_t$ are equal.  Moreover, there are sets of $n_t$ that make this ratio very close to $0$.  Therefore, $\bar{p}$ is *inadmissible* for quadratic loss.

Comment: @whuber well spotted!

Comment: I think we have gone off on a tangent here.  The OP's question asked what assumptions and model make $\bar{p}$ "the estimator", not about the relative merits of $\bar{p}$ versus $\hat{p}$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate agreed! I believe that if we assume that $d_t∼Bin(n_t,p_t)$ and additionally $p_t = \mu + \epsilon_t$ with $\epsilon_t$ s  iid with zero expectation, then $\bar{p}$ is a good estimator. Under which conditions is it the MLE?

Comment: @Papo please see the edit.

Comment: @teucer Thanks for this, I deleted my comment. Perhaps you could use Bootstrap in order to get confidence intervals for the second estimator coming from the same model. Check the second code please.